# How to disable return message from pubnub using pubnub php v4 sdk

Tags: pubnub

I am new in PubNub PHP SDK v4. Here's my concern that I would like to ask.

When I ran PHPUnit `--filter Nameofcontroller`, I've noticed that pubnub sdk is returning messages as such: `[2018-08-08 05:16:09] PubNub.DEBUG:`

I want to disable it. Is there a way on how to do it? I can't find it in pubnub's documentation guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Disable Debug STDOUT Output PubNub PHP SDK 4.0

You can disable the STDOUT print statements by setting up your own NullLogger following the [PubNub PHP Troubleshooting guide](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/pubnub-php-sdk-troubleshooting-guide).  Using a **`Psr\Log\NullLogger`** instead of `Monolog\Handler\ErrorLogHandler` is the best option.

```
use Psr\Log\NullLogger;
use PubNub\PNConfiguration;
use PubNub\PubNub;

$pnconf = new PNConfiguration();

$pnconf->setPublishKey("pub_key");
$pnconf->setSubscribeKey("sub_key");

$pubnub = new PubNub($pnconf);

$pubnub->getLogger()->pushHandler(new NullLogger());
```

> Using this code sample you can redirect all log message output to your desired location such as `/dev/null`

Reference: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/460